# How to make query with a list of constraints

Tags: c#, sql

I am not sure if I phrase the title correctly. But here is the question:

I have

1. A `list<int>` `orderIDs`, with over 2 million elements, created in C#
2. A table in SQL Server with two columns: `"name"`, and `"orderID"`
3. No permission to create temp table in the DB istance.

What is the fastest way to retrieve the set of names for each orderID in C#?

On top of my head, I could

- a) loop through orderIDs, and change query every time, but that is
  too time-consuming
- b) concatenate all orderID in the "WHERE ", but it will make the query very long

Any better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of "retrieve all name with given orderID", do you really mean "retrieve the set of names for each orderID"?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this with `Linq, SQL Query, Stored Procedure, etc...`? showing some existing code would be most helpful..

Comment: Sounds like a case for a batch job...

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Where are the IDs coming from?  Are they already in the database somewhere so that you can join to them in your query?

Comment: Is your "list of int orderIDs" a List<int> data structure in C#, or a table in your database, or something else?

Comment: How many unique orderIDs are in the table?

Comment: @DStanley: Those IDs are coming from external source (some flat file), and I do not have permission to create temp table in the DB instance

Comment: @mbeckish: There are over 10 million unique orderIDs

Comment: If you try the 2nd approach you will discover at least 2 database limits.  One is the number of query parameters you can use.  Another is the number of items you can have in a list.  Why do you need 2 million records?

Comment: There might be over 10 million unique ids, but whatever you did to get the 2 million you wanted can also be used to get the names.

Comment: Since the number of orderIDs in your DB is only 5x the number of orderIDs in your query, you might be better off just fetching them all from the DB in one query, and then use LINQ to join with your list of orderID's from the flat file.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Yes, you are right. It won't let me concat all orderIDs.

Comment: If you have no permission to create a temp table, can you have a *regular* table in the database, that you can fill for this process? You would have to delete the data directly afterwards, though.

Comment: @mbeckish: That is what I think about. But I guess if I fetch all rows into a flat txt file, then add it into my project as embedded reourse, then the app will be very large.

Comment: What percentage of the total number of orders do you expect to retrieve? 20%?

Comment: @Jodrell: the percentage varies from data sets, generally 5%~30%

Comment: @Mavershang - Not sure why you would store the fetched records in a flat file.  But that should probably be addressed in a separate question.

Comment: I think @mbeckish probably has the right idea, if you read the data as an asynchronous stream you won't have to hold all the name strings in memory. Depending on the resources available on your server you could make a number of filtered queries and run them concurrently, asynchronously combining the results, especially useful if order is unimportant.

Comment: shame you can't alter the schema just a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can push the flat file to a location that SQL Server can read it, then consider the `OpenRowset` ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190312.aspx)) or `OpenDataSource` ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx)) functions.

These allow you to treat a flat file as a row set that you can join to other tables in your database.

Be aware of contention though - if you have multiple clients wanting to find names for their own list of IDs, you'll need to create a distinct named copy of the file for the duration of each query.